# Flutter implementing Animation using Hook

Tags: flutter

in flutter i'm trying to use `Hook` 3rd packages which that introduced in [this link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks)

my code is below implementation and i would like to know how can i use `Hook` for that

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scale Example',
      home: ScaleTransitionExample(),
    );
  }
}


class ScaleTransitionExample extends StatefulWidget {
  _ScaleTransitionExampleState createState() => _ScaleTransitionExampleState();
}

class _ScaleTransitionExampleState extends State<ScaleTransitionExample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Tween<double> _tween = Tween(begin: 0.1, end: 1);

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this);
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: ScaleTransition(
              scale: _tween.animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.ease)),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.check, size: 100.0, color: Colors.green),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('forward'),
              onPressed: () => _controller.forward(),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('reverse'),
              onPressed: () => _controller.reverse(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

for using `Hook` i made this file as function:

```
Tween useTweenForAnimationController (AnimationController animationController){
  return Hook.use(_TweenControllerForAnimationHook(animationController:animationController));
}

class _TweenControllerForAnimationHook extends Hook<Tween>{
  final AnimationController animationController;
  const _TweenControllerForAnimationHook({@required this.animationController});

  @override
  _TweenControllerForAnimationHookState createState() =>_TweenControllerForAnimationHookState();
}

class _TweenControllerForAnimationHookState extends HookState<Tween,_TweenControllerForAnimationHook> {
  Tween<double> _tween;

  @override
  void initHook() {
    _tween= Tween(begin: 0.1, end: 1);
  }
  @override
  Tween build(BuildContext context)=>_tween;
}
```

and i changed `StatefulWidget` implementation to this:

```
class ScaleTransitionExample extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final tweenWidgetAnimController = useAnimationController(duration: kThemeAnimationDuration);
    final tweenController = useTweenForAnimationController(tweenWidgetAnimController);

    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: ScaleTransition(
              scale: tweenController.animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: tweenWidgetAnimController, curve: Curves.ease)),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.check, size: 100.0, color: Colors.green),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => tweenWidgetAnimController.forward(),
              child: const Text('forward'),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => tweenWidgetAnimController.reverse(),
              child: const Text('reverse'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now, on this line of code:

```
scale: tweenController.animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: tweenWidgetAnimController, curve: Curves.ease)),
```

i get this error:

> error: The argument type 'Animation' can't be assigned to the
>   parameter type 'Animation'. (argument_type_not_assignable at
>   [xxxxx] lib\samples\scale_widget.dart:29)

i think hook function should be easiest than my implementation